# What am I doing wrong with doPost?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a simple apps script that is deployed as a web app return a text file for the user to download. However, I can't even get the doPost to work! All of the similar questions on SO are saying that you need to republish a new version each time to get it to work, but I am doing that and I still get nothing. In fact, all I am getting is HTML code as a string telling me that the URL doesn't exist.

Here is my code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(e);
}

function testPost() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

  var params = {
    "method": "POST",
    "payload": "this is a test string to see if i can make a post work",
    "followRedirects": true,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I am clueless about why I can't run the testPost function and get a response from the doPost. I must be missing something completely simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when a user visits the url you want it to automatically download a text file? For that you need to use the [downloadAsFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output#downloadasfilefilename) method, to tell the browser to download the file rather than display the content. Your code should look like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
  var fileName = 'Ipsum.txt';
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(text).downloadAsFile(fileName);
}
```